# Injected Javascript in ReactJS File Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In the render of the SearchBar class, I can't get the unordered list with the injected Javascript to show in the browser. Is there an error in the method, or is there something more I have to do to get injected Javascript to appear?

```js
import React from 'react';
import './searchbar.css';

const sortByOptions = {
  "Best Match": "best_match",
  "Highest Rated": "rating",
  "Most Reviewed": "review_count"
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    renderSortByOptions() {
  return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
    const sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
  });
}
  render() {
   return (
     <div className="SearchBar">
       <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
         <ul>
           {this.renderSortByOptions()}
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div className="SearchBar-fields">
         <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
         <input placeholder="Where?" onChange={this.handleLocationChange} />
       </div>
       <div className="SearchBar-submit">
         <a>Let&#39;s Go</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   )
 }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix by adding a return statement after the renderSortByOptions() method.

```js
 import React from 'react';
import './searchbar.css';

const sortByOptions = {
  "Best Match": "best_match",
  "Highest Rated": "rating",
  "Most Reviewed": "review_count"
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    renderSortByOptions() {
  return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
    const sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
    return <li

        key= {sortByOptionValue}
       >{sortByOption}</li>;
  });
}
  render() {
   return (
     <div className="SearchBar">
       <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
         <ul>
           {this.renderSortByOptions()}
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div className="SearchBar-fields">
         <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
         <input placeholder="Where?" onChange={this.handleLocationChange} />
       </div>
       <div className="SearchBar-submit">
         <a>Let&#39;s Go</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   )
 }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return inside your map statement like so:

```
 renderSortByOptions() {
   return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
     return sortByOptions[sortByOption];
   });
 }
```

Alternatively you could keep your variable assignment and return that instead:

```
renderSortByOptions() {
  return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
    const sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
    return sortByOptionValue;
  });
}
```

Note that this is plain Javascript functionality and will work regardless of framework :)

Comment: That got it to appear. It's not showing up the way that I expected though. At least it's showing now. I'll have to look for why it's displaying incorrectly. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem Jeff! If you can't figure out how to do it consider asking a new question with some more code and an explanation of what you want. People will usually help pretty quickly :)

PS, if my answer did answer your question you should "accept" it, this way others will know you don't need the help anymore and won't waste their time writing an additional answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, it will also help others with a similar problem know which answer is correct :)

Comment: No problem, we were all new once! Simply click the checkmark on the top left of my answer.